# iphone development bank payment

Tags: iphone, payment, account, bank

I have been hired to develop an iphone app. My customer is non-technical and wants me to take care of everything.  So, I want to develop and manage the app within my existing account, but have his bank information so he gets paid automatically.

But itunes connect seems to only allow a single bank account for all my apps.

Is there a way to route payments for just his app?

Apologize for posting this to programming forum . . .

Answer (score 5):

The easiest thing is to create a new account for your customer. Add yourself as a developer on his account and develop the app using their certificate. That way everything is clean and uncomplicated

Comment: Thanks. To clarify -- the app has to be developed using their certificate?  I can't develop with my own certificate and then just upload their itunes connect account?

Comment: It can be developed using any certificate (or none if you want to just use the simulator). When it comes to submission you will need to sign the app with the clients certificate

Answer (score 0):

That's the problem, as I see it.  My customer has to get a developer account and create certificate, etc. -- all technical stuff he doesn't want to deal with.  I think Apple may have not thought through the process of programmers-for-hire.